# NoClassDefFoundError with correct dependencies for Bukkit Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently modifying an old Bukkit Plugin of mine to run a Discord Bot with the **JDA**-API. After I got an

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/impl/JDAImpl
```

error I added the JDA-jar and every other library needed to my dependencies. This worked quite well, until I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocketFactory
```

But as soon as I add this very dependency to my `*.jar*`-File OR as a dependency in the artifact settings, i get the

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/impl/JDAImpl
```

again - and it's driving me crazy!

Any ideas what I can do there? I wonder how this is possible, because I am not deleting any dependencies or anything - just adding the `com.neovisionaries.ws` - library.

Comment: What build-tool you use?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA to build the artifact

Comment: Please add some screenshots of how you configured the including of the `.jar`-files

Comment: I would recommend using Maven to build Java projects. If you get stuck feel free to repost your question and send me a message on here or tag me on here. Here is a link to help: [Creating a plugin with Maven using IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-plugin-with-maven-using-intellij-idea/)